# Group data on X-axis

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SharePoint list with 5 options (questions).  Each option has a dropdown with values 1-6. The user (employee of a company) needs to select an option, then select a value from the dropdown and hit Submit. The selected value is unique. In other words, if the user selects the value 1 for the first option, that value cannot be chosen again. Here's an example form -

```
Category                 Rank  
------------------------------
1. Work/Life Balance      4
2. Compensation           2
3. Commute                3
4. Work                   1
5. Development            5
```

After filling the form, the data looks likes this on the Sharepoint list -

```
Employee        Manager   Work/Life  Compensation  Commute   Work   Development  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. Employee 1   Manager 1       2          4          3        1         5
2. Employee 2   Manager 3       1          3          4        5         2
3. Employee 3   Manager 1       5          4          2        3         1
4. Employee 4   Manager 2       4          1          5        2         3
```

I'm able to get the Y-axis (for Rank) on the report just fine. The X-axis needs to display each category grouped by each Manager. Here's a sample of how I want it to look like -

[image]

Each colored bar on the X-axis is a Manager. This is my first time with SSRS (2012) and I'm just not sure how to accomplish this. If this is not possible, will moving the data to a SQL table in a different layout help? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could aggregate each employee's response into an average in your dataset (I'm assuming you know how to do this):

```
               Averages (just pretend)
Manager        Work/Life  Compensation  Commute   Work   Development  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. Manager1     2          4             3         1      5
2. Manager3     1          3             4         5      2
3. Manager2     4          1             5         2      3
```

Then you can use the categories as you have, with the manager as the series field. Pretty sure that should achieve what you're looking for.